Flood fill on a network in parallel
I'm trying to create a program that contains a list of node objects with the class:
class Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connections = []
        self.label = None

Here elements of connections will be other node objects. The objective is to perform flood fill on the list of nodes so that each node ends with a label indicating what connected network it is a part of. The current code is as follows:
import multiprocessing as mp
import random

def flood_fill_labeling(node_list):
    n = len(node_list)
    L = [i for i in range(0,n)]
    i = 1
    while len(L)>0:
        l = random.choice(L)
        node_list[l].label = i
        L.remove(l)
        # Recursion here (if node has an edge)
        if len(node_list[l].connections)>0:
            L = flood_recursion(node_list[l].connections,i,L,node_list,1)
        # End recursion
        i+=1

def flood_recursion(connected_nodes,i,L,node_list,depth):
    # Used to fill connected components in flood fill
    if len(connected_nodes)==0:
        pass
    else:
        next_rec=[]
        for node in connected_nodes:
            # If already labelled, pass
            if node.label != None:
                pass
            else:
                # Apply label and remove index from L
                node.label = i
                L.remove(node_list.index(node))
                # Append connections to next recursion of flood fill
                for next_node in node.connections:
                    next_rec.append(next_node)
        # Flood fill the next set of connections
        # If at depth 1, i.e. Just started recursion, split into parallel processes
        if depth == 1:
            L = mp.Pool().starmap(flood_recursion,[([j],i,L,node_list,depth+1) for j in next_rec])
            L = list(set.intersection(*map(set,L)))
            # Current issue is each process is returning a different variation of L. Intersection doesn't seem to resolve this
        else:
            L = flood_recursion(next_rec,i,L,node_list,depth+1)
    return L


Basically, select a node index that hasn't received a label yet at random, give it a label and recursively label its connecting nodes until all connected nodes have the same label.
The algorithm works for the serial case but when I try to parallelise the problem I'm coming across issues.
Once the processes are finished, L is returned as a 2D list of different results as expected but taking the intersection or union of them doesn't seem to fix the issue as many nodes are left unlabelled at the end.
Any help with this is appreciated.
